# XML / Xpath -- getTextContent() -- I'm looking to get each attribute as a string

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have the following XML and Xpath code..   with node.getContent() I get a string return of the complete SUID element.. what is the best what to get each element and construct a new object with recid,suid,group

THANKS!

```
</newticket>
        <suid>
          <recid>8848DC1650664B0294B194B1D6F61AA0</recid>
          <suid>RST40024</suid>
          <grouplink_recid>C66A8FF92F0F4CE9825A4C42ADDBF09A</grouplink_recid>
        </suid>
        <suid>
          <recid>AF12C557C9DD4EA087155CC263204668</recid>
          <suid>uiuyiitest</suid>
          <grouplink_recid>C66A8FF92F0F4CE9825A4C42ADDBF09A</grouplink_recid>
        </suid>
      </account>
    </newticket>

 XPathExpression escalationIdXpath = xpath.compile("//newticket/account/suid");
        NodeList idNodes = (NodeList) escalationIdXpath.evaluate(doc.getDocumentElement(), XPathConstants.NODESET);
        Node node;
        String escalationId;
        Element urlElem;
        for (int i = 0; i < idNodes.getLength(); i++) {
            SuidType suid = new SuidType();
            node = idNodes.item(i);
            fulltext= node.getTextContent();
            System.out.println(fulltext);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways you could achieve this...

### You Could

Get the child nodes of the `suid` node and compare there node names with the expected values of the `SuidType` object...

### You Could

Use new XPath's to find each child node of the `suid` node...

```
for (int i = 0; i < idNodes.getLength(); i++) {
    SuidType suid = new SuidType();
    node = idNodes.item(i);
    XPathExpression subPath = xpath.compile("recid");
    String recid = ((Node)subPath.evaluate(node, XPathConstants.NODE)).getTextContent();
    subPath = xpath.compile("suid");
    String suid= ((Node)subPath.evaluate(node, XPathConstants.NODE)).getTextContent();
    subPath = xpath.compile("grouplink_recid");
    String groupLink= ((Node)subPath.evaluate(node, XPathConstants.NODE)).getTextContent();
    // Apply values to the object...
}
```